# Multi WebRTC pages rendering

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, express, webrtc

I'm currently working on a MultiWebRTC site using [this, Muaz khan github](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection) and now I'm trying to do user authentication using MySQL, express, and node.js. But the HTML webRTC pages are already rendered normally so when I set ejs as my view engine it doesn't work. and if I make those webRTC pages ejs it shows but I can't do any video conferencing
how can I render my ejs pages and still render the webrtc pages at the same time?
Thanks in advance for your answer. 
part of server.js where i render page

```
var express  = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('/Audio+Screensharing');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Download any demo from [demos directory](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/tree/master/demos) and copy the HTML.

Paste html to ejs or cshtml or aspx or php or anywhere.

Now modify the "ejs" file.

**Search these two lines:**

```
<script src="/dist/RTCMultiConnection.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

**Replace above lines with:**

```
<script src="https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/dist/RTCMultiConnection.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

One last step is still remaining.

**Search following line on the same "ejs" file:**

```
// by default, socket.io server is assumed to be deployed on your own URL
connection.socketURL = '/';
```

Replace above line with following:

```
// this line is VERY_important
connection.socketURL = 'https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com:443/';
```

**Now any RTCMultiConnection demo will work on any ejs/cshtml/php/aspx file.**

> Please don't forget that **"HTTPs" is required**. Camera, Microphone or Screen works only on HTTPs.

There is a tutorial (documentation) page as well, explaining all above steps:

- [Getting Started guide for RTCMultiConnection](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md)

There is a YouTube video presentation as well:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jqtC7mSTCgk

You can store/keep/save "room-id" on MySQL; you can even use following snippet:

```
$.get('/owner-info', function(eachUser) {
    // everyone opens a room
    connection.open(eachUser.userid);
});

btnJoinAUserByHisUserId.onclick = function() {
    var joinThisUserId = 'userid-xyz'; // you can read this line from server

    // connect two users usign this method
    connection.join(joinThisUserId);
};
```

> Remember, each and every person can open unique room. Anyone can join any other person using his roomid. [for more information](http://www.rtcmulticonnection.org/docs/userid/#comment-3300183279)

RTCMultiConnection complete documentation is available here: http://www.rtcmulticonnection.org

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i already did that but when i did this;
var express  = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('Audio-video-screen');
});

The functionality stopped working, calls couldn't be made

Comment: You don't need to run socket.io on your own server. Use socket.io from herokuapp (the one I referred above).

Comment: Thank you for your reply @MuazKhan, i'm not running my own socket.io, i'm trying to log in user with mysql and express, that's why i'm trying to render pages with ejs but when i render the pages with ejs functionality stops working

Comment: Are you running HTTPs? Please modify your question (above) and include "server.js" codes (e.g. express.js usage codes)